# Mysql select with multiple tables and multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, multiple-tables

If I have three tables like:

suppliers (sID: integer, sName: varchar, description: varchar); With sID as primary key

```
+-----+-----------+-------------+
| sID |   SName   | description |
+-----+-----------+-------------+
| 1   | Supplier1 | Desc1       |
| 2   | Supplier2 | Desc2       |
| 3   | Supplier3 | Desc3       |
| 4   | Supplier4 | Desc4       |
| ... | ...       | ...         |
+-----+-----------+-------------+
```

products (pID: integer, pName: varchar, size: varchar); With pID as primary key

```
+-----+----------+------+
| pID |  pName   | size |
+-----+----------+------+
| 1   | Product1 | S    |
| 2   | Product2 | M    |
| 3   | Product3 | B    |
| 4   | Product4 | M    |
| ... | ...      | ...  |
+-----+----------+------+
```

menu (sID: integer, pID: integer, cost: varchar); with sID and pID as foreign keys

```
+-----+-----+------+
| sID | pId | cost |
+-----+-----+------+
| 1   | 4   | 10   |
| 2   | 16  | 20   |
| 8   | 1   | 5    |
| 8   | 2   | 8    |
| ... | ... | ...  |
+-----+-----+------+
```

The only relation between *suppliers* and *products* is given by the *menu* table.

How can I select the names of all suppliers that supply all products?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would get the ids.  Simply aggregate and count:

```
select m.sid
from menu m
group by m.sid
having count(distinct pid) = (select count(*) from products);
```

I'll leave it to you to get the supplier name, which you can do using `in`, `exists`, `join`, or even a correlated subquery.